# Div Overflow Scroll

Tags: css, html, scroll, overflow

There is a code block like this;

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="title">Title Text</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="block">Block text1</div>
    <div class="block">Block text2</div>
</div><!--Content End-->    
</div>
```

I change css overflow attr of content class like "overflow:scroll;" . But when I change this feature,  overflow attribute of all div element changing. I want to fixed title class ,that don't scroll. How can I do this?

Comment: Paste the CSS your are using, so we can point out what is wrong in it..

Comment: .wrapper .content {overflow:scroll;}

Comment: Yes it's wrong, that will cover the title div as well as it's inside the .wrapper div. Both answers posted are correct. Try them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
div.content { overflow: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your css is

```
div.content { overflow:scroll; }
```